# requireJS and namespaces

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am trying to use a namespace with `requireJS` and facing some problems. So far I have:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
      jquery: [
          'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min'
        ],
      jqueryUI: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min',
      main: 'http://mysite.com/main'
  }
});
```

and then I am trying to load

```
require(['jquery', 'main'], function($) {
    myApp.core.init();
});
```

where `main.js` contains my namespace variable like `myApp` - however it's telling that jQuery is undefined for the `myApp` which infers that all my code inside

```
(function(myApp, $, undefined) {

}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}, jQuery));
```

wont' work ? Can someone help ?

Comment: Is this the real code? If it is, then you're using requirejs in the wrong way...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a read up on [how modules are supposed to be used in the AMD format](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define). For this to work correctly you need to re-factor your main.js to be a module definition. For example

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    // Setup my module

    return {
        // return an object, or function etc
    }

});

// Nicer way - http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar
define(function(require){

    var $ = require('jquery');

    return {

    }

});
```

If, for some reason you cannot modify the main.js code [you can also make use of the `shim` option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) in RequireJS. An example might be:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'main': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'myApp'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a module template (always use something like this)

```
define(function(require){
  var $ = require('jquery');

  var myApp = function(){
  };

  // etc...

  return myApp;
}
```